# Добавьте на свой рабочий стол папку из Pycharm

Tags: python

Помогите с задачей по питону. Необходимо через PyCharm добавить на свой рабочий стол папку, в ней создать 3 текстовых файла: test_1.txt, test_2.txt, test_3.txt.

Затем переименовать файлы на: rename_1.txt, rename_2.txt, rename_3.txt.

После этого удалить созданную папку.

Все операции выполнять с помощью встроенных функций библиотеки os

Answer (score 0):

Можно таким кодом:

```py
import os
import shutil

PATH = ""

os.mkdir(os.path.join(PATH, "some_folder"))  # Создание папки

for i in range(1, 4):
    with open(os.path.join(PATH, os.path.join("some_folder", f"test_{i}.txt")), 'w') as f:  # Создание трех файлов
        pass

for i, file_name in enumerate(["test_1.txt", "test_2.txt", "test_3.txt"]):
    os.rename(os.path.join(PATH, os.path.join("some_folder", file_name)), os.path.join(PATH, os.path.join("some_folder", f"rename_{i}.txt")))  # Переименовывание файлов

shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(PATH, "some_folder"))
```

PS1: PATH - это путь, где надо создавать папку.

PS2: Тут используется еще и `shutil`, так-как если использовать `os` для удаления, то возникают проблемы с правами.

Comment: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape Эта ошибка каждый раз, как я прописываю путь на рабочий стол.

Comment: C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Рабочий стол - хотя путь прописан верно.

Comment: Все разобралась. Нужно двойную черту ставить, чтобы избежать ошибки в юникоде. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @Татьяна, если вам помог этот ответ, поставьте на него зеленую галочку.